# What's best practice for using backbone.js with localStorage for IE7 and IE6?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, backbone.js, local-storage

I'm developing an application with backbone.js, back and socket.io, and I'm running into trouble with localStorage on ie7 and ie6.

Have you chased IE7/Window Phone compatibility with backbone before?  What was your solution for storing the model client-side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on Bryan Bailliache's answer above, I created a seamless Amplify backend for Backbone.js, you can check out https://github.com/dev360/Backbone.amplify. Hope it's useful.

Answer (score 4):

The [AmplifyJS](http://amplifyjs.com/api/store/) project has a storage abstraction that

> amplify.store is a wrapper for various persistent client-side storage systems. amplify.store supports IE 5+, Firefox 2+, Safari 4+, Chrome, Opera 10.5+, iPhone 2+, Android 2+ and provides a consistent API to handle storage cross-browser.

Since it works on IE 5+, that should fix the troubles your having.

Unfortunately I have not done WinPhone compatibility but I have done IE 7+ compatibility for Windows and the AmplifyJS project met my requirements.

Comment: Sweet.  If it works on IE7, it usually seems to work on IE7 Mobile.

Answer (score 2):

I needed the same thing.

As this question is 1 year old and https://github.com/dev360/Backbone.amplify last commit 2 years old and not up to date with current Backbone.localStorage version

I did a new Backbone.localStorage using Amplify
https://github.com/fadomire/Backbone.amplifyLocalStorage

I'll try to keep it up to date and fix issues, but no guarentee.

Answer (score 0):

The Backbone.js page has a demo "ToDo List" app that has a localStorage adapter that comes with it. I would modify this, check for window.localStorage and fallback to using cookies or an ajax call to the backend.